# Update multiple column with activeAndroid

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, activeandroid

I want to update multiple cell of single row with active android. 
some thing like this,

```
    new Update(Question.class).set("UserAnswer ="+answerID,
                                    "UserAnswerType = "+userAnswerType)
                               .where("QID = ?", questionID).execute();
```

but that will gives me error. is there any other way to do this? or am i missing something?

Here is my Question.class for reference

```
@Table(name = "Questions")
public class Question extends Model {
@Expose
@Column(name = "QID")
private Integer ID;

@Expose
@Column(name = "AnswerID")
private Integer AnswerID;

@Expose
@Column(name = "UserAnswer")
private Integer UserAnswer;

@Expose
@Column(name = "UserAnswerType")
private Integer UserAnswerType;

//Getter and setter methods for fields

public Question() {
    // You have to call super in each constructor to create the table.
    super();
}
}
```

Comment: can you insert the question . class?

Comment: @Erik-JanWestendorp , have updated my question for reference

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below. I have done it in one of my project and it worked fine.

```
 String updateSet = " UserAnswer = ? ," +
                    " UserAnswerType = ? ";

 new Update(Question.class)
     .set(updateSet, answerID, userAnswerType)
     .where(" QID = ? ", questionID)
     .execute();
```

Following similar pattern for any number of columns will work. In case if you have `Boolean` type fields in your table, [this issue](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/449) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**We Can achieve it like this way.**

```
            StringBuilder data=new StringBuilder();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()))
            {
                data.append("Name = '"+name.getText().toString()+"',");
            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(age.getText().toString()))
            {
                data.append("Age = '"+age.getText().toString()+"',");
            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(empCode.getText().toString()))
            {
                data.append("EmployeeCode = '"+empCode.getText().toString()+"',");
            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobNum.getText().toString()))
            {
                data.append("MobileNumber = '"+mobNum.getText().toString()+"',");
            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(adress.getText().toString()))
            {
                data.append("address = '"+adress.getText().toString()+"'");
            }
            String str=data.toString();

    //-------------and update query like this-----------------

    new Update(EmpProfile.class).set(str).where("EmployeeCode = ?", empCode)
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String x="sent = 1,file = "+n.getString("file");
new Update(Messages.class)
    .set(x)
    .where("id = ?", lid)
    .execute();
```